# Loop a list by aligning the elements to the left or right depending on their parity

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify an existing component within an application, the idea is that a single list of elements is traversed, these elements have a position field, when the position is odd the element must appear on the left and when it is even on the right. I explain it with a piece of "pseudocode" as simple as possible so that it is easy to understand.

```
<div class="container">
   while(!lista.isEmpty()){
     <div class="c-box if(posicion%2 == 0){'c-right'}else{'c-left'}">{{item}}</div>
   }
</div>
```

The problem is that there are not always the same elements in both columns and the items can have variable heights, so the most obvious solution 
 that would be:

```css
.container{
}
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

It does not work because when several odd elements are chained, they are placed side by side due to float.

Another solution that I have tried is to assign a lateral margin to force the position to the left and right but in this case there is a gap to the left or right of each of the fields:

```css
.container{
    }
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:50%;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

Another posible solution could be use grid but this make the side column to be always the same height and this is not desirable because some items display other elements in same c-box dynamically.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.c-box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.c-left {
  grid-column-start: 1
}

.c-right {
 grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left" style="height:80px">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

I know that using 2 divs with two columns and going through the list twice this problem would be solved but I cannot apply that solution in this case, the list must be traversed as it appears in the first code, I have the possibility to use flex-box or any CSS solution but I have made many attempts without any results. It is probably an easy problem but I do not find the solution.

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you thought of `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` inside a flex container with `flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: stretch;`? This will remove your inline left/right classes.

Comment: Those of the .even and .odd classes is a requirement of the OP. This factor is not marked by its position within the DOM, but each item is going to arrive with a value (which can be even or odd) and it may be the case that several even items go one after the other. I think in this case the :nth-child(even) is not usable.

Comment: You can change the .odd and .even for .left and .right, that is more easy to understand.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem, my apologies! Could you use your `float` solution with a `clear: left/right` on each element? Not tested, just an idea.

Comment: Using clear doesn't work, in this example it makes the last item of the right appear below all the left items and it should be stacked to the top with the other right items